# Mobile Application Development Tools

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns, mobile-application

Subject  - A group of developer looking for Mobile Application Development guidelines(Preferably for Android platform).

We have been searching different sources for information regarding application design phase. Specifically different parts such as Sketching, Prototyping, Navigation flow diagrams...etc. We are more interested to know regarding Navigation flow diagrams. Could anyone please share some good resource where we can reference different types of annotations for our application state. In short...

What will be the best practise to describe my application's different states in form of diagrams? In order to circulate(in team) an idea of how our application will flow in order to accomplish user's goal.

P.S.  Such guidelines should be provided by google? Or these sort of documentation objects should depend on individual design team?

Thank you in advance,

Happy Coding!
Krio

Comment: I can't understand why is it being tagged as off topic? Check faq 1) software tools commonly used by programmers
2) matters that are unique to the programming profession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the style Google uses on their SDK, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html. While they do not provide an explicit guide to creating these diagrams, the general principle is easy to understand and follow.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I might have to be creative to develop my own notation style to annotate threads such as AsyncTask, As this guideline document has not much information regarding annotation of  background threads. :)

Answer (score 0):

I built my Android application with an SDK and Adobe Flash Builder. The following URL was useful because there are code snippets that handle the physical buttons and the rotation features of the mobile devices.

http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_456-voip-android-integration-voip.html

I hope you will also find it useful.